# unable to run phpunit tests on api rest served by a docker with php-fpm and nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a docker-compose.yml file where i configure following service :

- nginx (web) -> server_php_web_1
- php-fpm (php) -> server_php_php_1
- mysql (db) -> server_php_db_1

My nginx serve an api rest php over https and vhost is : **back-php.dev** with associated and working certificates

From outside docker i can curl back-php.dev without problem

there is a directory test where i can run the test when running this command :

```
docker exec server_php_php_1 php /code/vendor/phpunit/bin /code/tests
```

But when i m running tests i obtains the following result :

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: back-php.dev
```

I have also tried the following :

```
docker exec -it server_php_php_1 /bin/bash
curl server_php_web_1
```

And i can curl successfully the container running nginx, but how can i do if i want to test the following url **https://back-php.dev**

Here is the structure of docker-compose.yml simplified :

```
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            - code-network
        extra_hosts:
            - "back-php.dev:127.0.0.1"
        links:
            - php

    php:
        build: ./
        networks:
            - code-network
    db:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        networks:
            - code-network

networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

And the dockerfile associated to php :

```
FROM phpdockerio/php74-fpm

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y \
        php7.4-pdo \
        php7.4-json \
        php7.4-curl \
        php7.4-mbstring \
        php7.4-common \
        php7.4-mysql

RUN echo "ENV_NAME=dev" >> /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: Looks more like a "how to set up Docker" question than a "how to use PHPUnit" question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extra_hosts:
      - "back-php.dev:127.0.0.1"

Create hostname mapping "inside containers" not outside(host).

---

So if you want to access you app from "outside"(host) you'll need to create a new entry on `/etc/hosts` and add

```
<container_ip> back-php.dev
```

To find your container ip do

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

---

Update1:

```
php:
  ...
  links:
    - back-php.dev:web
```

Comment: i m already able to curl back-php.dev from outside, i mean my localhost environment.
I can't curl back-php.dev from my container running php-fpm. This is where i execute my tests, php-cli is installed in it.

Comment: I add update1. add links to `php` to access your `web`. You have to map hostname from where you want to access, not the destination

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue today, I solved making the Docker Host available under the alias of `localhost` from the PHP container, so that the PHP Container will run the tests based on the Application's URL (usually localhost), the Application's URL (`localhost`) will go to Docker Host, so Docker will serve the HTTP/HTTPS request according to the Container mapped to reply to the HTTP/HTTPS request, usually the WebServer (NGINX Container) under HTTP on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443. then WebServer will send the request to PHP Container to run the PHP code.

I included the host `localhost` on PHP Container appointed to Docker Host IP, usually `192.168.65.2` for me. Get your Docker Host IP with this command:

```
docker run -it --rm alpine nslookup host.docker.internal
```

Request flow:

```
[Test @ PHP Container] --> Docker Host ([NGINX @ WebServer Container]->[PHP Code @ PHP Container])
```

My suggestion should be something like this:

```
...
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            - code-network
        extra_hosts:
            - "back-php.dev:127.0.0.1"
        links:
            - php

    php:
        build: ./
        extra_hosts:
         - "localhost:192.168.65.2"
        networks:
            - code-network
...
```

You must replace:

- "localhost" according to the HTTP Request from your PHP test;
- "192.168.65.2" according to the Docker Host IP.

I hope this helps you :)